# Why is LOAD WITH HEADERS statement only importing the first row of my dataset?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am attempting a project where I must import a dataset into neo4j. After trying to use the `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS` statement, I noticed that it only imported the first row from my file. After realizing this, I attempted to use the apoc plugin to run `CALL apoc.periodic.iterate` thinking that since my dataset had 16719 rows, it needed to be able to wait for each row to be called on so it would not fail.

**apoc.periodic.iterate attempt:**

```
    CALL apoc.periodic.iterate
(
    "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Video_Games_Sales_as_at_22_Dec_2016.csv' as row
    WITH row
    RETURN row",

    "MERGE (g:Game)
    ON CREATE SET g.Name = row.Name,
        g.Release = row.Release,
        g.NASales = row.NASales,
        g.EUSales = row.EUSales,
        g.JPSales = row.JPSales,
        g.OtherSales = row.OtherSales,
        g.GlobalSales = row.GlobalSales  

    MERGE (p:Platform)
    ON CREATE SET p.Name = row.Platform

    MERGE (c:Genre)
    ON CREATE SET c.Type = row.Genre

    MERGE (v:Publisher)
    ON CREATE SET v.Name = row.Publisher

    MERGE (x:Developer)
    ON CREATE SET x.Name = row.Developer

    MERGE (r:Rating)
    ON CREATE SET r.Rating = row.Rating

    MERGE (g)-[:ON_PLATFORM]-(p)
    MERGE (g)-[:GENRE]-(c)
    MERGE (g)-[:PUBLISHEDBY]-(v)
    MERGE (g)-[:DEVELOPEDBY]-(x)
    MERGE (g)-[:RATED]-(r)",

    {batchSize: 10000, iterateList: true}
)
YIELD batches, total 
RETURN batches, total;
```

Even after running this new statement, it only imported the first row and all relationships.
In an attempt to figure out what I am doing wrong, I would like to know if anyone has experienced a similar issue?
With that being said, if you see where I am messing up, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: What is LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Video_Games_Sales_as_at_22_Dec_2016.csv' as row
    WITH row
    RETURN row returning?

Comment: can you give me sample data of Video_Games_Sales_as_at_22_Dec_2016.csv? So that I can test it on my end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may have to do with the fact that you do things like

```
MERGE (g:Game)
```

which may overwrite the same node every time.

Normally you do

```
MERGE (g:Game {Name: row.Name})
```

assuming that `Name` is an identifying property.

Also, make sure that you have a `CONSTRAINT` set for the `Name` property.

Same of course for all the other node types that you are using.

Comment: After creating the constraints, it seemed to have worked. Thank you for your response.